# Convert ES6 arrow function to ES5 function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What is the `ES5` equivalent of the below code?

```
Object.keys($location.search()).forEach( key => ($location.search()[key] == null || $location.search()[key] == "") && $location.search([key], null));
```

I tried to replace the `=>` with just a simple `=`, that resulted in a error however.

How do I convert the above code to the `ES5` syntax.

Comment: Missing `function` use `function (key){ ...}`

Comment: Ups, sorry. Added the missing `=>`. Thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either convert it into a `function` yourself or use something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to do it for you

```
Object.keys($location.search()).forEach(function (key) {
    return ($location.search()[key] == null || $location.search()[key] == "") && $location.search([key], null)
});
```

Comment: I copied this code, and works among all browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To replace a arrow function you can´t just use a =, you need to use a regular function statement like:

```
(param) => {
  //code block 
}

function(param) {
  //code block
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser and your time!

Answer (score 1):

Just use an anonymous function (see documentation on [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)):

```
Object.keys($location.search()).forEach(function (key) {
    return ($location.search()[key] == null || $location.search()[key] == "")
            && $location.search([key], null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser and ur time!